# XML data file has been changed, but changes don't appear on html page in gmaps

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-maps

I inherited a site that uses Google Maps API, so I wasn't a part of the set up. I had to change some dealer information in the xml files, but once changed, the changes did not appear in the dealer search. Any help would be appreciated. The page is here: http://basalite.com/dealers_contractors.html?hLeadType=Dealer

Comment: Is it a caching issue?  If you don't tell the browser the file has changed, it won't update until your refresh the page (or sometimes in some browsers clear out the cache), sometimes loading the updated XML in the browser will work.  What would be the new information that we should be looking for?

Comment: Thank you-I think you are indeed correct, it was a caching issue. I appreciate your response. I haven't worked with XML much, so this was great information.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a caching issue. If you don't tell the browser the file has changed, it won't update until your refresh the page (or sometimes in some browsers clear out the cache), sometimes loading the updated XML in the browser will work.